# Using \DeclareMathVersion

Tags: fonts, math-mode

It is my understanding that `\DeclareMathVersion` can be used to switch between math font variants.  I am wondering how this can be used in a document that leverages two fonts: Times Roman for body text and Garamond for captions and headings.  (The style is certainly unconventional, but works quite nicely.)

Times, through `\usepackage{txfonts}` and Garamond through `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}` both provide math fonts.  What is required for the following example to typeset?

While I believe `\DeclareMathVersion` is the solution, documentation is on it is sparse.  However, I have seen several LaTeX typeset books which pull this switching off.  May be related to [Change math font only in some parts of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{txfonts}

% ...

\begin{document}
 % This will be in times
 \[ \int e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)dx \]
 % We want this in Garamond
 % ...
 \[ \int e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)dx \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX allows only 16 math font families (`\fam`) in one document. This restriction is not easy to raise. If you use `\DeclareMathVersion` to switch math fonts, you may meet the problem.

Comment: Correction: 16 math alphabet families (Variable family).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After defining new math versions with `\DeclareMathVersion`, you can use `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, `\SetMathAlphabet`, `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\SetSymbolFont` to set all math families manually. You must rename the math family names. You must be sure there are no more than 16 math *alphabet* families (but symbol familis can be more). And there may be encoding problems.

Anyway, although it's quite complex, it is posible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% text fonts
\renewcommand\rmdefault{txr}
\newcommand\gmfamily{\fontfamily{mdugm}\selectfont}

%%% New math versions
\DeclareMathVersion{varnormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{varbold}
\newcommand\txmath{\mathversion{normal}}
\newcommand\txboldmath{\mathversion{bold}}
\newcommand\mdmath{\mathversion{varnormal}}
\newcommand\mdboldmath{\mathversion{varbold}}

%%% Math symbol fonts
%%% some examples only
% Math letters from txfonts and mdugm
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{txmi}{bx}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varnormal}{OML}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varbold}{OML}{mdugm}{b}{it}
% Math operators
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}
% Math symbols
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varnormal}{OMS}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varbold}{OMS}{mdugm}{b}{n}
% Large symbols
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varnormal}{OMX}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varbold}{OMX}{mdugm}{b}{n}

%%% Math alphabets, at most 16 families
%%% some examples only
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{it}

\begin{document}

This is Times font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\txboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}

\gmfamily\mdmath
This is Garamond font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\mdboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hello, how can we know the "short name" of the fonts. For example, `txr` for `Times`, `mdugm` for `Garamond`.

Comment: Regarding the comment above: [fonts - Quickest way to search for valid \fontfamily arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118969/quickest-way-to-search-for-valid-fontfamily-arguments)