# how to select math font in document

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I want to show in one document different font examples of math fonts, for example Latin Modern, Times and Charter.

I know the command `\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}`, but have no idea how to combine that with a math environment.

Comment: You would have to define math versions. But depending on the fonts involved this can be quite complex. Better make external graphics/documents and import them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's a bit complex in LaTeX. Note that the definitions of math symbols are complex. Math fonts are quite different with text fonts.

You may want to read the document of NFSS: [LaTeX2 font selection](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf), section 3; and the documented source code of LaTeX2e: [The LaTeX 2 Sources](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section 42.

For examples, any math font package is OK. I suggest `mathptmx.sty`, it is typical and relatively simple. e.g.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
```

This (re)defines the `letter` math family. And the command

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
```

in LaTeX2e kernel makes `letters` family to be default alphabet font.

People usually don't use many font families in one document. For an example of mixed math fonts, see also [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/using-declaremathversion/19257#19257).

It is not only annoying, but also impossible to define many math fonts in one document. In TeX, the number of math alphabet fonts is limited to 16. As Ulrike Fischer said, if you just want to show the results of a few math font packages, just produce some graphics and import them into the document. It is much easier.

Comment: To be fair you *can* use more than 16, just not within the same math formula, but you may need to tinker with low level TeX commands. Within the same math formula you can still do something with `\mathchoice`/`\hbox` if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 46):

*Update Aug. 2013*: Since posting the initial version of this answer back in Sept. 2011, (at least) two more Unicode math fonts have joined the TeX/LaTeX scene: TeX Gyre Termes Math (to go with TeX Gyre Termes, a Times Roman clone) and Tex Gyre Pagella Math (to go with TeX Gyre Pagella, a Palatino clone). I've edited the example code below to include these two math fonts; the total of math fonts shown is now up to six [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riaFY.png).

---

*Update May 2018*: Over the past five years or so, several additional Unicode math font families have become available. I've updated the code and screenshots shown below to include the following, additional math fonts: `Stix`, `Stix Two`, `Libertinus`, and `DejvaVu`. I have deliberately not included `Neo Euler` as its development status is "abandoned". I also haven't included `Minion Math` since it is a commercial font that's not available free of charge.

---

As the other answers and comments have already pointed out, it's not easy in **pdfLaTeX** to switch from one math font group (say, Computer/Latin Modern) to another. The packages I'm familiar with which have matching text and math fonts are the default Computer/Latin Modern group (loaded if no other font group is specified), `mathptmx` (Times Roman look), and `mathpazo` (Palatino). There are also the `txfonts` and `pxfonts` packages, which give you Times and Palatino, but the hinting and glyph substitution isn't as good as with `mathptmx` and `mathpazo`. Within just the last few months, the `newtxmath` (and `newtxtext`) packages have come along; they correct virtually all of the shortcomings of the `txfonts` package and add quite a bit of new functionality as well. I'm not familiar with math fonts designed specifically to go with *Charter* text fonts.

Even though it's *not* straightforward (or even possible?!) to switch between entire math font families within the same document *if*  you use `pdfLaTeX`, it's actually quite easy to do so in `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`. The following MWE gives a demonstration of ten different matched text and math fonts: Latin Modern, XITS/XITS Math, TeXGyre Termes, TeXGyre Pagella, Palatino/Asana Math, and Cambria Math, as well as (addition 2018-May) Stix, Stix Two, Libertinus, and DejaVu.

See also the web page [A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) for a comparison of various free math fonts available for (pdf)LaTeX users.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac,unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

%% Load 10 math fonts; 1 of them with and without some "stylistic sets"
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[version=xits]
\setmathfont{Stix Math}[version=stix]
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=stix2]  % https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[StylisticSet={1,2,8}, version=stix2_128] 
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=termes]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=cambria]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=pagella]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[version=asana]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=libertinus]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[version=dejavu]
%%\setmathfont{Neo Euler}[version=euler] % status: "abandoned"

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\newcommand{\abc}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\ligs}{\ ff fi fl ffi ffl}
\newcommand{\abctextrm}{Text roman:  \abc\ligs}
\newcommand{\abctextit}{Text italic: \ \ \textit{\abc\ligs}}
\newcommand{\abcmathit}{Math italic: \ $\abc$}
\newcommand{\formulas}{%
  $\displaystyle
   \int_{0}^{1}\! x^{2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \sfrac{1}{3} 
   \qquad
   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}
   \qquad 
   \mathcal{ABC}\ \mathfrak{ABC}\ \mathbb{CNQR}$}
\newcommand{\doall}{\abctextrm\par\abctextit\par\abcmathit\par\formulas}

\begin{document}

%% Latin Modern (the default on most systems)
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\mathversion{lm}
\section*{Latin Modern Roman, Latin Modern Math}
\doall

%% Various Times Roman clones
\setmainfont{XITS}
\mathversion{xits}
\section*{XITS, XITS Math}
\doall

\setmainfont{STIX}
\mathversion{stix}
\section*{STIX, STIX Math}
\doall

\clearpage
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\mathversion{stix2}
\section*{Stix Two Text, Stix Two Math}
\doall

\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\mathversion{stix2_128}
\section*{Stix Two Text, Stix Two Math w/ stylistic sets 1, 2 \& 8}
\doall

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\mathversion{termes}
\section*{Termes, Termes Math}
\doall

\clearpage
%% Palatino clones
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\mathversion{pagella}
\section*{Pagella, Pagella Math}
\doall

\setmainfont{Palatino nova}[UprightFont=*-Regular,
             BoldFont=*-Bold, ItalicFont=*-Italic]
\mathversion{asana}
\section*{Palatino nova, Asana Math}
\doall

%% Others

\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{Cambria}
\mathversion{cambria}
\section*{Cambria, Cambria Math}
\doall

\clearpage
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\mathversion{libertinus}
\section*{Libertinus Serif, Libertinus Math}
\doall

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\mathversion{dejavu}
\section*{DejaVu Serif, DejaVu Math}
\doall


%%  Neo Euler Math has status "abandoned"
%\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
%\mathversion{euler}
%\section*{Palatino Linotype, Neo Euler Math}
%\doall
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's been already pointed out that **unicode-math** has the concept of `\mathversion` that's more efficient than stating `\setmathfont` anew. You may wish to update your answer after looking at page 8 of the documentation.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for this suggestion. I've updated the code and provided an additional paragraph to highlight the use of this facility.

Comment: Now there are only a few opentype math fonts. Only 4 for free: Latin Modern Math, XITS Math, Asana Math, Neo Euler; 2 commercial: Cambria Math, Minion Pro; and some in development: Lucida Math, TeX Gyre(?).

Comment: The concept of math versions is in LaTeX2e's NFSS, say, `normal` and `bold`. You can use `\mathversion` in pdfLaTeX. `unicode-math` inherits the concept and makes it easier to use.

Comment: @LeoLiu -- thanks for this. I've inserted a sentence in the answer noting the relative paucity of OpenType-based math fonts, and I've also inserted a sentence linking to a survey of free math fonts for pdflatex users. About Cambria Math: It's not free, but seems to be standard on Windows distributions; it's not free for others, but since it costs only $35 (for text and math fonts), it's a real bargain compared with the cost of the soon-to-be-released Minion Pro math font package.

Comment: Are there any such fonts where the lower case x is not so fancy? I want something a bit more like the capital X. None of these extra curls and curves.

Comment: @user1271772 - Short answer: Check out the [mathastext](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathastext) package. Longer answer: My (very limited!) understanding of math font history is that in math mode, lowercase letters are generally drawn in italic style (with the "curvy x"...) rather than in upright/"Roman" style in order to make it unambiguous what's a variable ("x" or "y") and what's an operator. Consider $\sin x + \tan x$, where `\sin` and `\tan` are generally typeset in the (upright) text font. Also, note that `$x\times y$` is unambiguous if `x` is set in italics.

Comment: @user1271772 - Still another answer: You may wish to consider using the `DejaVu Math` Opentype math font: its math-italic `x` glyph is among the least-curvy such glyphs I've come across. However, you may not like other features of this math font.

Comment: See this Community Wiki question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available