# Getting Started with Minion Pro, XeLaTeX and mathspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, mathspec

I have just started using Minion Pro and `mathspec` for my work and now I have the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setallsansfonts[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\setallmonofonts[Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ubuntu Mono}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
\exchangeforms{phi}
```

Now I have a number of questions:

1. What fonts can you use for `mathbb`, `mathcal`, `mathfrak`, ... I mean I don't even know what I have to choose from here.
2. I want Myriad Pro Bold whenever I have either math or text bold. How can I do that?
3. I have been playing around with the `mathspec` commands but often I get the "too many fonts" error. How do I keep track of how many fonts I have defined?
4. Also my mono font does not work. In other words `mathtt` is just `mathrm` in my text.

Comment: You might be interested in [Minion Math fonts](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html) by Johannes Küster.

Comment: 700 Euros is kind of too much ... but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 21):

Using `unicode-math`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % always load before mathspec or unicode-math
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math} % try sans-style=upright
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=6},%
             BoldFont={Myriad Pro Bold},BoldFeatures={LetterSpace=3}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},LetterSpace=3]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Crystal}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathsf/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Myriad Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfsf/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Myriad Pro Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]%
            {Minion Pro Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathsfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]%
            {Myriad Pro Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfsfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]%
            {Myriad Pro Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathtt->\mathup]{Crystal}
\let\mathbf\mathbfsf
\let\mathbfit\mathbfsfit
\AtBeginDocument{\let\phi\varphi}
```

(N.B. `unicode-math` loads `fontspec`, `xltxtra`, and `xunicode`)

1. `mathbb`, `mathscr`, &c. all have sensible defaults with this. If you want, say, serifed `mathbb`, you could add `\setmathfont[range=\mathbb/{Latin}->\mathup,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Hoefler Text Engraved}`. The `/{Latin}` part applies it only to uppercase latin letters.
2. Use `BoldFont` and `BoldFeatures` with `fontspec`. For `unicode-math`, I just used `\let` commands, although I know there's probably a more elegant way to do this.
3. Removing `MnSymbol` frees up a lot of math alphabets, and `unicode-math` increases the limit.
4. Apparently Ubuntu Mono is [bugged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-font-family-sources/+bug/867853); I couldn't use it, so I tested with Crystal. And it works.

---

**EDIT:** To use Minion for even more symbols, you could replace the `\mathup` line with:

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek},\question,\exclam,\mathdollar,%
    \percent,\ampersand,\lparen,\rparen,\plus,\comma,\period,\mathslash,\mathcolon,%
    \semicolon,\less,\equal,\greater,\backslash,\rbrack,\lbrack,\atsign,\vert,\lbrace,%
    \rbrace,\times,\div}]{Minion Pro}
```

Comment: This can be simplified by removing the `/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}` part as it is the default so no need to explicitly set it. You can also use `vargreek-shape=unicode` package option instead of the `\AtBeginDocument` thing to get the same effect.

Comment: @KhaledHosny, I was sort of nervous about excluding the `/{...}` part since I've seen `unicode-math` try to use operators in the new font, too. Or is that only for `mathbb`?

Comment: This works but it has two flaws: 1) the new math font (XITS? awful name btw) is quite ugly and different compared to MnSymbol (summation signs for example). 2) I have lost \prime 3) How do I change the numbers for math font to osf as well?

Comment: @Hesam (1) You could try loading Asana-Math.otf instead, or swapping in Cambria Math from Office. There's a comparison [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30066/9092). (2) Use `^\prime` or `'`. (3) You can specify OpenType features in `\setmathfont` – e.g., `\setmathfont[range=\mathup,Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}`.

Comment: 1) Conversely what font is better suited to XITS? It seems to me Minion is not a good text font to accompany it? 2) I was using `^\prime` and I tried `'` no luck 3) I tried it but did not work, should I do it for all `\setmathfont` commands? 4) My fraktur font is bold for some reason! 5) The commands `\hat`, `\check` don't work properly and produce very large symbols for those with subscripts and superscripts (and my syntax is fine).

Comment: @Hesam (1) It's designed for [STIX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/) – hence the name. (2) That's odd; maybe post an MWE? (3) Add `Numbers=OldStyle` to all the existing `\setmathfont` commands, or at least the ones you set numbers in. (4) Asana-Math.otf has lighter Fraktur; you can either use it outright or change just `\mathfrak` using `\setmathfont[range=\mathfrak]{Asana-Math.otf}`. (5) If you aren't just completely turned off by `unicode-math`, you should make a new question for `\hat` and `\check`.

Comment: It seems this needs updating; this fails with `Range alphabets cannot include alphabets referring to bf, sf…`.