# How to create my own TeX mathfont? Is there a certain method to realize the idea?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would one design a math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75022/how-would-one-design-a-math-font)

Recently, I'm interesting in mathfont for TeX. I want to create a mathfont by myself. Can anybody recommend me some softwares and procedures.