# Changing font of mathematical functions (ln, exp, etc.)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, mathspec

SOLVED: see edits #1 and #2 below.

I'm trying to set up a XeLaTeX document that uses a sans-serif math font (Myriad Pro) with a serif text font (Arno Pro). Because Myriad Pro does not have full math support, I'm using the MdSymbol package to access mathematical symbols. However, when calling built-in mathematical functions such as \ln or \exp (and presumably \cos etc.), the font reverts to Computer Modern.

Is there a way I can get these built-in functions correctly displayed in Myriad Pro?

As an additional question, I would like to have in-line math in the main text font (Arno Pro) rather than the math font (Myriad Pro). Can anyone suggest a convenient way of doing this?

MWE below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{ArnoPro-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{MyriadPro-Regular}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
      j_0 = \frac{j_{kin}}{\exp{\frac{- \alpha_c F \eta}{RT}}} \\
      \alpha_c = - \frac{RT}{F \eta} \ln{\frac{j_{kin}}{j_0}}
   \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example from a larger document. The text is (correctly) in Arno Pro, and the maths is (correctly) in Myriad Pro, but \ln and \exp produce text in Computer Modern.]

EDIT #1: the \ln issue can be resolved by adding the following:

```
\setmathrm{MyriadPro-Regular}
```

The answer was found here: [XeTeX/mathspec math environment font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88138/xetex-mathspec-math-environment-font?rq=1)

EDIT #2: the in-line font issue can be solved using the instructions in this page: [Use different math font in inline-style and display-style formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249760/use-different-math-font-in-inline-style-and-display-style-formulas)

However, the discussion there, and the comments on this thread, have convinced me that it is better to write mathematical expressions in the same font whether they are in-line or in dedicated environments. Since switching between serif and sans-serif in a line of text is jarring, I have opted for just using serif font throughout.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have math displays in Myriad and inline math in Arno and it would make little sense anyway.

Comment: It makes perfect sense from a display point of view - maybe not this specific pairing of fonts, but it's a work in progress.

Comment: Sorry, but from a mathematical point of view a serif eta and a sans serif eta mean different things.

Comment: Okay, fair point, it makes sense in certain contexts. For my purposes, I think it makes sense, as eta is referring to overpotential, and this is not affected by serifs. For a strictly mathematical paper, it could cause problems; thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for your input. The suggestion is incorporated into the edited question above.

Answer (score 1):

Although @egreg gave one method, `\setmathrm`, it is also possible to change the operator font to something other than `mathrm`.

In `unicode-math`, this is the `\operatorfont` command, for example

```
\operatorfont\mathsfup
```

In classic LaTeX, you can redefine the `\operator@font` command to a different font than `\mathrm`. Remember to `\makeatletter` before using a command name with `@` in it, and `\makeatother` when you are done.