# Where to get TeX Math Font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fun, computer-modern

I apologise for a question that might seem naïve to many. However, I encountered a problem and a couple of hours of an intensive research didn't bring any results. Basically, I would like to have a line engraved into a ring in the same font that TeX uses for math. I am to send the font in question to the jeweller, along with the line. However, I am in confusion as to *what* I am supposed to send. I found out that the font would probably be either Computer Modern or Latin Modern; but when I tried to download that, I got a number of fonts and none of them seemed to be what I was looking for. Also, since the line includes the symbols 'á' and 'š', I need the font to have these.
If you could be so kind as to advise me on where to get the right font, I'd be grateful. I am enclosing the line so that you can picture what I mean.
Thanks in advance.
Z.

Edit: What I did not know was that the PDF output was, in fact, a vector graphic, so I'll try to send that to the jeweller instead and see what happens.

```
$\forall d \in days : d > 0 \iff (áName \cup šName)$
```

Comment: Ask the jeweller whether a PDF file with the required text printed in the required font will do. If not, ask what the jeweller needs. Then get back to this site with a more specific request, perhaps.

Comment: I guess your "couple of hours of intensive research" already came up with this one, but I'll link it in anyways: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/

Comment: Your line should rather be $\forall d \in \mbox{days} : d > 0 \iff (\mbox{áName} \cup \mbox{šName})$, i.e. math in math mode, text in (restricted) text mode.

Comment: You shouldn't write `days` in math mode. You should write `\mathit{days}` instead, to get the spacing between the letters right. Same goes for `áName` and `šName`.

Comment: Also, you might consider `\implies` instead of `\iff`. With `\implies` you're saying "if the day is after today, then áName and šName are unioned". With `\iff` you're *additionally* saying "if áName and šName are unioned, then the day must be after today", i.e. "áName and šName are *not* unioned before today." But maybe that's what you intended.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The jeweller said he needed either the specific font or the line itself in vector graphic. Since I wasn't familiar with how to obtain either of those, I figured the first one would be an easier option. You are right, John, that I already came across the link you posted but the package includes numerous fonts (e. g. CMU Bright Bold, CMU Serif Bold Italic etc.) and I have no idea which one to send, nor which ones have math (and Czech) support.

Comment: `\textit` or even `\textup` might be better than `\mathit` as `\mathit` does not allow for national chars

Comment: (I wasn't going to get into a discussion about the line itself, though I appreciate your corrections, but maybe I should clarify that the line is to be read "A day is positive if and only if A and B are united".

Comment: via the link John posted, you can access a file called `cm-unicode-0.7.0-ttf.tar.xz` -- that's the archive containing the TrueType version of the fonts. I'm assuming that's the format your jeweller can handle most easily. Regular Roman is the file `cmunrm.ttf`. Italic is `cmunti.ttf`. PS: a PDF file, as produced by TeX *is* a vector graphic. So that might work as well.

Comment: @Zuzana Vector graphics will be easier. Using LaTeX it is a five-minutes work. Which vector format is suitable for your jeweller?

Comment: BTW if it should mean "A day is positive if and only if A and B are united" then the second part should rather be \mbox{A} \cap \mbox{B} \neq\emptyset. :-)

Comment: PPS: »The jeweller said he needed either the specific font« ...I'm wondering what he's going to do with the font once he's got it: use the TeX code to produce -- a PDF? Or bypass PDF creation by feeding the code directly to a Lua-powered engraving machine?

Comment: @Zuzana Oh I see what you mean now. Regarding Przemysław's suggestion, I think `A \cup B` is fine. It doesn't make strict mathematical sense, but the intention (and romanticness) is clear.

Comment: @Zuzana -- you might add to the question the fact that the jeweler can handle the line as a vector graphic.  i think there might be a more useful answer for that approach (though i can't give it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try to send the PDF output to the jeweller and let you know what happens. Thanks also for the thumbs up for the romantic aspect of my question! Przemysław, I see what you mean. I'll discuss it with the other set in the evening :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/ seems to have many variations of the Computer Modern font. Are any of those what you are looking for?

Comment: What the person downvoting you without a comment probably meant to say is that this is more like a comment than an answer. Besides, the problem has already been solved. In any case, shame on the downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question, but I'll do my best.

There are many (and I mean MANY) packages to accommodate encoding of different "delicate" symbols like rare letters from little known languages. Vietnamese, Chinese, Slovenian (my language; you've probably never heard of it) etc. are all represented by plethora of CTAN packages. So to start, we're going to solve your issue of displaying `á` and `š`.

Let's start with the easier one, `á`. We can get a solid result even *without any additional packages* (don't get confused by `amsmath` package, I only let it in because without it functions `\forall`, `\in`, `\iff` and `\cup` can't be compiled). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\forall d \in days : d > 0 \iff (\acute{a}Name \cup šName)$
\end{document}
```

Here you can see, that `á` got substituted by `\acute{a}`. But now we have a problem. If you only intend on using this command in math mode, that's fine, but if you want output it in text mode *that won't work*. To achieve the latter, we must turn to a different command:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
\'{a}
\end{document}
```

Here we see that `á` is once again replaced, this time with `\'{a}`.

Now onto `š`. Once again, in math mode, a substitution should suffice:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\forall d \in days : d > 0 \iff (\acute{a}Name \check{s}Name)$
\end{document}
```

And in the normal text:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\v{s}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you want to have serif `á` and/or `š`, you *don't have to use math mode*! You can simply *italicise* the whole thing altogether:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\textit{\'{a} \v{s}}
\end{document}
```

**BUT THIS IS NOT THE BEST WAY TO GO ABOUT!!!**

Now I'm going to bring out the big guns: encoding. Who would want to write `\'{a}` and/or `\v{s}` every time he/she wants to write such a character in his/her native language? No one. That's why LaTex has a wonderful package called `babel`. Let me show you (a quick note: I'm using `slovene` package, because I'm from Slovenia (google it) you can use *any* version of `bable`, but I personally advise you to use the one that corresponds to your native language; hence the "standard" `babel` formula: `\usepackage[INSERT YOUR LANGUAGE HERE]{babel}`):

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
áš
\end{document}
```

Simple as that! I have to mention that you MUST include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as it indicates the *compilation protocol*. All languages with exotic letters must do that as the adherent Tex compiler isn't advanced enough to handle these newer symbols. And once you've done that you're set! Just watch (note: don't get confused by `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`, it's just a bit of code that removes space before paragraph, so everything is aligned correctly):

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

This is a normal text: Upám, da ti je bil ta odgovor v pomoč!\\
This is an italicised text: \textit{Upám, da ti je bil ta odgovor v  pomoč!}\\
This is symbol usage in math mode: $\check{z} + \check{s} + \check{c} = \acute{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]
**Important:** Do NOT try to write `š`, `č`, `á` etc. in math mode. This will only produce a large amount of errors. Remember: WE USE **ONLY** MATH ACCENTS IN MATH MODE!

And a quick tutorial on how to change the font:

```
\documentclass[13,legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

This is a normal text: Upám, da ti je bil ta odgovor v pomoč!\\
This is an italicised text: \textit{Upám, da ti je bil ta odgovor v pomoč!}\\
This is symbol usage in math mode: $\check{z} + \check{s} + \check{c} = \acute{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]
Note the `\usepackage{times}` I added to change text font from Computer Modern to Times New Roman. Easy, isn't it? Well, of course you must first *know* font name in order to compile it. If you compile the code, you can see that *math font* DIDN'T change. If you want to accommodate the latter as well, you can perform some other LaTex tricks, which are a bit more complicated, but I'm sure you'll get through. Just read this brilliant post: [how to select math font in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document).

I hope this post was helpful. I wish you countless hours of fun with LaTex!