# Change the sans serif math font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

I would like to change the sans serif math font to, say, Kurier, while keeping the roman font as the default. In other words, I'd like to change the font that is used with \mathsf whithout affecting the behaviour of the other math commands. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Changing (OpenType/TrueType) math fonts with `unicode-math` in xelatex/lualatex is very easy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the file `kurier.sty` and you'll find the lines (not in the same places)

```
\DeclareOption{regular}{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{kurier}}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{kurier}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathsf{kurierbold}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{bx}{n}
```

that tell you how to do in your case. The first line reveals the font family internal name, the other two what's used for `\mathsf`. So, add

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{kurier}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{kurier}{bx}{n}
```

to your document preamble. The first declaration tells LaTeX that `\mathsf` must use Kurier, changing it into bold when the math version is bold.

Answer (score 0):

For XeTeX you can say in the preamble something like

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsf{Liberation Sans}
```