# How to Change the Font of Math Symbols in Latex?

Tags: fonts

How to change the font of math symbols in latex? For example, for the summation symbol, I can produce the following two symbols. Are there any other font for them?

[image]

For the first sum I used `\usepackage{mathptmx}` and for the second I used the default font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does [how to select math font in document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30049/32888) help?

Comment: I found the `mathpazo` package, and the `fonttable` package to be a pretty good guideline for how to set up a custom math font.

Comment: See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html. Basically, there are a number of choices. If you tell us which one you want to use, we can help if you have any problems. But there is no point duplicating a listing here which is better mainted by the LaTeX Font Catalogue!