# How to change the font for the forall symbol?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to make the `\forall` symbol a bit curvy, without changing the fonts of other symbols. I found at [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259140/how-to-change-the-font-of-math-symbols-in-latex) that different packages might offer a different font. Is anyone aware of a way to change the font of only the `\forall` symbol to a more curvy one?

Comment: Welcome, you know the font designer had many sleepless nights to get the symbols in the font look just right? If you go through with what you want, your document will look like a ransom letter to an expert. Experts see a different symbol that doesn't fit from miles away.

Comment: See the second answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document I do however agree with @Johannes_B that your document will most likely end up looking hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some experiments with upside down calligraphic A's and a lambda combined with `-`. As for the result, well, it will not win Miss Universal Quantifier 2018.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\newcommand{\curvyall}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathcal{A}$}\!}
\newcommand{\curvymirror}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{190}{$\mathcal{A}$}}\!}
\newcommand{\curvyup}{\stackMath\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\stackinset{c}{0.2pt}{c}{-0.65pt}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.0]{-}}{\Uplambda}}\!}
\begin{document}
Mathcal forall: $\curvyall a:a = a$

Mirrored tilted mathcal forall: $\curvymirror a:a = a$

Uplambda forall: $\curvyup a:a = a$

Regular forall: $\forall a:a = a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Miss Universal Quantifier" – amazing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marjin. On my system, my first choice 'Mathcal forall' looked too tilted. So I am using 'Uplambda forall' now with a minor change in the position of the horizontal bar: `{-1.6pt}` instead of `-0.65pt}`. Looks great for my purpose :)