# How can I change the math font inside a document?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, newtxmath, eulervm

I need a solution for the following problem: I usually use newtxmath with libertine option to typeset all mathematical expressions. This time I need to typeset one special formula using eulervm, all other formulas should be displayed using newtxmath.

The following MWE shows what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{eulervm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

newtxmath:
\begin{displaymath}
   E = mc^2
\end{displaymath}

eulervm:
\begin{displaymath} % use eulervm font here. exactly this one is needed.
   4(\Phi^2x^2-y^2)(\Phi^2y^2-z^2)(\Phi^2z^2-x^2)-(1
\end{displaymath}

newtxmath again:
\begin{displaymath}
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Is this possible and does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Is the formula to be typeset with Euler exactly that one? Knowing the precise one is needed.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, I thought that maybe there was a general solution to this problem. I replaced the dummy formula with the exact needed one. 
I know that this formula makes no sense, it is just part of a logo ...

Comment: Related question, [how to select math font in document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the knowledge of the precise formula, we can set up what's needed for typesetting it with the Euler fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerletters}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulersymbols}{U}{zeus}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eulerlparen}{\mathopen}{eulersymbols}{168}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eulerrparen}{\mathclose}{eulersymbols}{169}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eulerminus}{\mathbin}{eulerletters}{129}
\newcommand{\setupeuler}{%
  \mathgroup\symeulerletters
  \mathcode`(=\eulerlparen
  \mathcode`)=\eulerrparen
  \mathcode`-=\eulerminus
}

\begin{document}

newtxmath:
\begin{displaymath}
  E = mc^2
\end{displaymath}

eulervm:
\begin{displaymath} % use eulervm font here
  \setupeuler
  4(\Phi^2x^2-y^2)(\Phi^2y^2-z^2)(\Phi^2z^2-x^2)-1
\end{displaymath}

newtxmath again:
\begin{displaymath}
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for checking, here's the same formula with `\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}`:

[image]