# How to bold the letter in equation in LateX effectively

Tags: equations, bold

Suppose I have an equation involve many letters:

```
    \begin{equation}
    \min   \|S-A\|_F^2  
    \end{equation}
```

How can I bold the letter in equation, such as `S` and `A` in the equation. We can `\bm{A}` for each letter in Equation. But any fast way since we may have a lot of letter in equation.

Comment: How about `\mathbf` ?

Comment: for each letter like, `\mathbf{A}` and `\mathbf{S}`?  I prefect some fast way, such as using some setting.  bold letter appear, not one by one using `\mathbf`

Comment: `\mathbf{S-A}` should work.

Comment: `\bm` would embolden everything, so `\bm{S-A}` is not a solution. *The* solution is indeed `\min\lVert \vc{S}-\vc{A}\rVert_F^2`, where `\vc` is an alias for `\bm`: use semantically oriented commands. Being boldface is an attribute of the symbol, not of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following line to the preamble worked for me to change the math font globally.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

But operators won't be bold. Adding following line made operators and numbers bold.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

Read [How to select math font in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30053/28557)