# confused about setting math fonts?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex

Is there a way to set the math font like all the `\set...font` commands from
the `fontspec` package. For example, if I wanted to use `LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf` as my main font and `LibertinusMath-Regular.otf` as my math font, is there any way of doing something like:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}
```

where I can simply set the math font just like any other font ? I tried
referring to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document) but the accepted answer seems to be using `lualatex` while I am using `xelatex` . They have used the `\setmathfont` command which for me produces an undefined control sequence error.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setmathfont` is defined in `unicode-math` package, use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Libertinus Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
```

There is also `Tex Gyre Pagella` and `Tex Gyre Pagella Math` fonts.