# Best font choices for comprehensive symbol coverage and hinting

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

What are the best current choices for pdfLaTeX text and math fonts if the critical criterion is typeface consistency and hinting?

Here are my constraints, in brief:

- pdfLaTeX support and, moreover, current "out-of-the-box" support by the arXiv (TeXLive 2020);
- Polished consistency between the math and text typefaces and comprehensive hinting;
- Given that, I would like the largest coverage of mathematical symbols.

In more detail: I write the LaTeX style files for the online journal "Theory of Computing." For years we have used `mathptmx` because this seemed to be the best option supported by the arXiv; many more options are available now that they run TL2020 (including `stix2`, `newtx`fonts, and `newpx`fonts). I am aware of such discussions as

[how to select math font in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30049/how-to-select-math-font-in-document)

which are of course very useful. The problem is that such small snippets do not indicate the breadth of coverage of the mathmatical typeface and the quality of hinting. If the community's sentiment is that there are several competitive options, it would be nice to hear about the optimal choices for specific fonts such as Times-like, Palatino-like, and Modern-like.