# Quickest way to search for valid \fontfamily arguments?

Tags: fonts, berry

Say I have a command like

```
\newcommand{\fntpal}[1]{{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont#1}}
```

used for changing the font of specific chunks of text to Palatino and I also want something similar for other fonts like Helvetica, Latin Modern Sans Serif, etc.

What's the quickest method to discover that the correct argument for Helvetica is `phv` and that for Latin Modern Sans is `lmss`?

I could have guessed the `hv` part but I would have never guessed the `p` in `phv` (now I know the reason why it's there, but this is not the point).

What I did was:

- check the relevant [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/helvetica/) page (nothing useful there);
- jump to the [Helvetica CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/psnfss-source/) and search for some hint in the documentation till I found the [inst.tex file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/psfonts/psnfss-source/helvetic/inst.tex).

This same method didn't work for Latin Modern (too much doc files there) and I had to randomly search the internet until I found the magic string.

So, is there some **general reference list** for this? And why this information is left out of the font catalogue pages?

**edit:** looks like someone on another group had a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/latexusersgroup/_dgg2Lyx0dg/tTU9rc9E-gcJ)  and was pointed to: http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/typographics.html (which isn't a complete list, however)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm afraid such a method doesn't exist.

In the Eighties, Karl Berry proposed a font naming scheme for TeX/LaTeX that ensured, as much as possible, that metric file names consisted of at most eight characters, which was a constraint forced basically by an operating system I don't want to mention; the same constraint was forced for file names on CD-ROM.

A “Berry name” consists of various parts:

```
S TT W [V...] [N] [E] [DD]
```

(the square brackets represent optional parts), where `S` is one letter denoting the *supplier* (`p` is Adobe, `b` is Bitstream, `u` is URW, and so on). What you're interested in is `TT`, two alphanumeric characters representing the family name.

The document “Fontname – Filenames for TeX fonts” by Karl Berry is available in the major TeX distributions with `texdoc fontname` or at [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/fontname/fontname.pdf) (or on CTAN). There you find a long list of two letter family names with the correspondence with the “real” font name.

Thus `phv` is “Adobe Helvetica”, while `bhv` can be “Bitstream Swiss 721” and `uhv` is “URW Nimbus Sans”.

Metafont based fonts don't follow the convention, so the family name for the Computer Modern Roman fonts is `cmr`. There is a family pair `mr` (Madrone) and the supplier `c` is Compugraphic; but `cmr10` does not conform to the Berry naming scheme, so it can't misunderstood for a (probably inexistent) “Compugraphic Madrone”. If this font did exist problems would arise, though.

This is the past, however. Nowadays operating systems have lifted the eight character restriction on file names (at least at user level). Suppliers of LaTeX fonts have started using freely file names and *no* convention is followed.

For instance, the Quattrocento font uses `Quattrocento-TLF` as family name, while Iwona uses `iwona` and Linux Libertine has `LinuxLibertineT-xxx` (`xxx` stands for a two or three letter addition. The `newpxtext` package uses family names such as `ntxr` or `ntxss`.

The shell command

```
locate /t1 | grep 'texlive/2012' | grep '\.fd$'
```

which should find all `.fd` files relative to the T1 encoding finds 286 files; another 59 are found with `/T1` (not all packages follow the recommendation that font description file names start with the encoding in lower case).

Basically, an instruction such as

```
\fontfamily{<string>}\selectfont
```

loads the font description file `<encoding><string>.fd`. Say we're using T1 as output encoding; then `\fontfamily{xyz}` would load either `t1xyz.fd` or `T1xyz.fd` (if existent on your system).

Choosing from these font description file names is the only reliable way to find out what fonts you have.

Instead of the `locate` command one can exploit the `ls-R` file name cache of TeX Live, on Unix systems:

```
grep -i '^t1.*\.fd$' $(kpsewhich --all ls-R)
```

Note. The `--all` option seems to be replaceable by `-a`, which is what I've always used, but the short option is not documented.

Comment: Very interesting. As a side note, if someone else does not have the `locate` command installed by default and feels too lazy to install it, it can be substituted with `find <path to texmf-dist directory> -name t1* | grep '\.fd'`

Comment: @dcmst There's a different method that uses the `ls-R` file name caches.

Comment: Searching in `ls-R` outputs 350 .fd files instead of the 287 of the previous method (TL 2013 here). Any idea what's the reason for the difference?

Comment: @dcmst I get 289 + 63 = 352 with `locate` and 369 with `grep`. The difference are 17 `.fd` files I have in `texmf-local`

Comment: ahhh sure, forgot about local and `T1`

Comment: And then there's `fontspec` with XeTeX and LuaTeX, where you don't even have `.fd` files...

Comment: @MartinSchröder `fontspec` computes a family name on the fly; using `\fontfamily` with it is possible, but requires to know what name has been assigned.

Comment: Neither the manpage of `kpsewhich` nor the CLI help shows an `-a` switch, but apparently it works.

Comment: @mafp The man page says “This  manual page is not meant to be exhaustive”; the full documentation mentions `--all` but not the short version `-a` (which works).

Answer (score 11):

```
 texdoc fontname
```

on texlive systems at least will lead you to Karl Berry's opus on font names.

Or it is available on the web as

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/fontname/fontname.pdf

`phv` is on page 27....

`lmss` isn't in there (as the document is too old) but it explains the basic idea behind the cryptic names. Of course the reason for the cryptic names (MSDOS and other similar 8+3 file systems) doesn't really exist any-more, but still hard to change now.

Answer (score 1):

Anselm Lingnau gives a little reference in his book "LaTeX Hacks". See page 236 (hack no. 67):

> Computer Modern Roman: cmr
>
> Adobe Times Roman: ptr
>
> Adobe Palatino: ppt
>
> ITC Bookman: pbk
>
> Adobe New Century Schoolbok: pnc
>
> Bera Serif: fve
>
> URW Classico ("Optima"): uop
>
> Computer Modern Sans: cmss
>
> Computer Modern Bright: cmbr
>
> Adobe Helvetica: phv
>
> ITC Avant Garde Gothic: pag
>
> Bera Sans: fvs
>
> Computer Modern Typewriter: cmtt
>
> Adobe Courier: pcr

(I left out those who are not free ware.)

Comment: adobe times roman (a) isn't free, and (b) is ptm in the berry scheme.  (a pity that lingnau's book is in german: it looks interesting, but i'm not about to buy it (at that price! kindle almost as expensive as paper) and then spend an age translating!)

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1. Load the package, then print out the family using TeX

**Step 1.** Make a document that contains "Hello world" in your desired font.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Hello world}
\end{document}
```

**Step 2**. Replace "Hello world" with `Encoding: \csname f@encoding\endcsname, font family: \csname f@family\endcsname`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Encoding: \csname f@encoding\endcsname, font family: \csname f@family\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

If the font is a weird symbol font, use `\typeout` and read from the console/log file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\textsf{\typeout{Encoding: \csname f@encoding\endcsname, font family: \csname f@family\endcsname}}
\end{document}
```

The PDF will be blank, but the log file will contain the encoding/family name.

### Remark. `fontspec`

Of course, for some fonts, you need to use `fontspec` to load it.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
Encoding: \csname f@encoding\endcsname, font family: \csname f@family\endcsname
```

This will print out [image: output].

While, after the `\setmainfont` in that specific document, the fontfamily is usable

```tex
\fontfamily{LatinModernRoman(0)}\selectfont Hello world
```

it is not recommended at all to rely on the `(0)` suffix.

Instead, use `fontspec`, and specify `NFSSFamily=...`. For example, see [The macros setmainfont and setsansfont do not accept the new command of a newfontfamily. Is there compatibility between them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462544/250119).

---

Reference:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/250119 has a guide.
- [Berry naming scheme list of LaTeX font families](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23592/250119)
- [Is there a list available for all TeX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12887/250119) (contains solution that search through `.map` files and reference to `fontname`)
- [How can I get a list of all \fontfamily{...}\fontseries{...} combinations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378623/250119) (contains solution that grep through `.fd` files)
- [What fonts are installed on my box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2305/250119) (contains solution that grep through `.fd` files and/or list `.map` files)
- [How can I test for the current font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14377/250119)