# DejaVu Serif Condensed: Matching math font using PdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode, pdftex

I like the DejaVu Serif Condensed font as text font, but I did not find an appropriate math font for it.

To overcome this, I thought about two possible solutions:

- Finding an existing math font that looks good combined with DejaVu Serif Condensed
- Using the `\SetMathAlphabet` command to use DejaVu Serif as math alphabet.

I'm really interested in this second point. Does this work and would it make sens? Or will this mess up with the math symbols (that have to come from another font)?

Up to now I did not manage to make this second point working, following the solution shown in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/using-declaremathversion/19257#19257).

Any suggestions?

So, here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scaled=.85]{DejaVuSerifCondensed}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{DejaVuSansCondensed}

% Math letters in Times font
\DeclareMathVersion{mathtimes}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathtimes}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\newcommand\timesmath{\mathversion{mathtimes}}

% Math letters in DejaVu font
\DeclareMathVersion{mathdeja}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathdeja}{OML}{dejavu}{m}{it}
\newcommand\dejamath{\mathversion{mathdeja}}

\parindent 0pt

\begin{document}

  Some text written in DejaVu Serif Condensed. And the math is as default in CM.
  \[
    \frac{a}{b} + c \cdot d = \sum \int E \, .
  \]
  Now I can change the math alphabet with 
  \verb|\timesmath|      
  \timesmath
  and the result is
  \[
    \frac{a}{b} + c \cdot d = \sum \int E \, .
  \]
  Now I would like to do the same, but with the DejaVu Serif font, but if I do this the same
  way, the command \verb|\dejamath|
  does not work, as \verb|dejavu| is obviously not the correct name for the font shape.
  \dejamath
  \[
    \frac{a}{b} + c \cdot d = \sum \int E \, .
  \]

  My question is now, how do I get the correct font shape (equivalent to \verb|txmi|) for
  DejaVu; and does it make sense after all to use such a font in this way. One problem is, that
  DejaVu produces quite big letters (that is why I used the \verb|scaled=.85| option).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a Minimal Working Example showing what you've tried and what doesn't work? (E.g. what error do you get? Or what output do you get?) That will make it easier for people to suggest a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I've been too busy yesterday to add a minimal working example. I did it now, with some explanation inside the example. I hope this makes my problem clear.

Comment: That is a lot clearer - thanks. Unfortunately, it won't work. When you tell LaTeX to use oml/txmi/m/it for mathtimes, LaTeX looks for a font definition file omltxmi.fd and reads it to figure out what you mean. That's fine for txmi because that file exists. However, there is no equivalent for dejavu i.e. omldejavu.fd does not exist. So to do what you want, you'd need to set up the font with the OML encoding which isn't part of the packages available (that I know of).

Comment: Why not try Arev for the symbol font? That's another derivative from Vera and it does have an OML font definition file. You could try loading the package arevmath, for example.

Comment: _Please_: Use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and fontspec. And forget about Type1 fonts and `inputenc` and `fontenc`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Maybe I'll try to use some combination of an existing math font and a text font that work well together. I actually wanted to avoid the use of XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX for several reasons, which I don't want to discuss here.