# How to make italic greek letter \lambda

Tags: fonts, math-mode, greek, italic

I need italic and non-italic `\lambda` in the same document. Since the `\mathit{\lambda}` does not work, I got idea to simulate italic by changing fonts (Times New Roman for italic lambda, and Latin Modern for non-italic).

I made the following example based on answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99596/different-font-family-in-math-mode) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}     % set math font to Latin modern math 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm} %change text font to Times New Roman


\DeclareMathVersion{mymath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{myletters}{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mymath}{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{myoperators}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{mymath}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}


\newenvironment{myfont}{\mathversion{mymath}}{}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\mathmyfont}{\myfont}

% Define lambda with Times New Roman font
\newcommand{\lambdaTimes}{\mathmyfont{$\lambda$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\textrm{Lambda in Latin modern:} \lambda \\
\textrm{Lambda in Times New Roman:}\lambdaTimes
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This example does not work, it produce `-` instead of lambda in Times font. What is wrong in this example?

Is there a easier way to make italic and non-italic lambda in the same document?

P.S. I am using Times New Roman in text mode, and Latin modern in math mode in document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Latin Modern math doesn't blend with Times New Roman. You're better using NewTX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

The text is in Times; $\lambda\lambdaup$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist in using Latin Modern math symbols, here's how you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}     % set math font to Latin modern math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm} %change text font to Times New Roman

\DeclareSymbolFont{myletters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uplambda}{\mathord}{myletters}{"15}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\textrm{Lambda in Latin modern:} \lambda \\
\textrm{Lambda in Times New Roman:}\uplambda
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with `Latin Modern math doesn't blend with Times New Roman`. Is it impossible to use these two fonts in same equation?

Comment: @Petar They're typographically incompatible with each other.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this. I was thinking that I can mix any two fonts. However, the previous example does not work if we for example include package `amsthm`. The error is that `\openbox` is already defined.

Comment: @Petar Load `amsthm` and `amsmath` *before* `newtxmath`.

Comment: @Petar You *can* mix any two fonts. egreg was talking about style and taste. Typographically incompatible means that they look bad together.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Ok, now I understand.

Comment: @egreg Now it works. But now my thesis looks really ugly with this math font. Latin Modern was much better. Do you know how to make italic lambda (or somehow different) and keep Latin modern as default for math mode.

Comment: @Petar Sorry, I beg to differ: your thesis will look ugly with Latin Modern math letters.

Comment: @egreg Ok, this was my subjective opinion.

Comment: @Petar I added what you were looking for.

Comment: Excellent, it works exactly what I wanted. Tnx a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use Lua- or XeLaTeX, I would recommend the package unicode-math:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document} 
\blindtext
$\mathup{\lambda}\lambda$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tnx for answer, however I am looking for solution in Latex, I forgot to specify this in question.

Comment: @Petar - Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX *are* LaTeX. Their difference to pdfLaTeX is that they use other underlying engines to accomplish the typesetting jobs.