# Use only \lambda in mathptmx

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mathptmx

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}

$\lambda = 3.14\ \Omega$
\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

When I added `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

[image]

The following figure is what I try to do. So I want to use only `\lambda` in `mathptm`. Is it typographically incorrect? Can you help me?

Note: [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229891/33075) Not exactly for me.

[image]

Comment: why the strange markup `$\lambda$ = 3.14 $\Omega$` with = not in math? rather than the more standard `$\lambda= 3.14 \Omega$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I asked the question, I wrote it like that. I read your warning carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229891/33075) minus the two letters `up` (`\lambda` instead of `\uplambda`):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareSymbolFont{myletters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{myletters}{"15}

\begin{document}
  $\lambda$ = 3.14 $\Omega$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I could not believe the answer was that easy. And the result is exactly what I want.

Comment: I look at the entire document. It looks like the lambda looks a bit dark. Can you check? More specifically here, `$\lambda = \dfrac{c}{f}$`

Comment: @Özgür What do you expect, when the lambda is taken from a *different* font?

Comment: You're right. I did not think in that respect. I was so concentrated on the document.