# Trying to get lambda font style

Tags: fonts

How can I get this lambda, taking into account i’m using `\usepackage{lmodern}` as the main document font.

[image]

Comment: Might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229883/how-to-make-italic-greek-letter-lambda

Comment: @Raaja Excellent related. It is the same `\lambda` of the package `newtxmath`.

Comment: @Sebastiano yes indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package textgreek provides commands for greek letters, such as `\textlambda`.

Comment: I suggest to improve the question, by providing a MWE that shows how the OP is solved by using your suggestion, provided that `lmodern` is used ;)