# create OML font encoding from a commercial font

Tags: math-mode, font-encodings

I've bought the legacy sans and serif font package and I've inserted it into my TeX/LaTeX distribution, through pltotf, vptovf an similar utilities.

Then I've created a package that allows me to use that fonts in math mode, as [I've shown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document/101187#101187).
However, I need to increase the stretch of some glyph boxes, for example the "f"-italic one, as shown in the picture below

[image: stretch of "f" glyph]

To get the second output, actually I need to add manually the `\,` instruction. So, how can I create the OML font encoding of legacy font, in order to adjust the skip between math glyphs?

In addition, is this the right way to get the results I mean? I must say that I wont create a command like `\def\f{f\,}`, because in my opinion it is a trivial resolution

Comment: TeX adds the italic correction after a "math italic" letter (if nonzero).

Comment: But I must insert the font as OT1, because it is the only encoding I have, and this encoding does not allow to add the italic correction, instead of OML

Comment: What's the italic correction for `f` in the font?

Comment: I mean that in cmmi the width of some glyphs are wider than the same glyphs in cmri

Comment: @egreg the interword space `\fontdimen2` must be zero for `TeX` to automatically insert the italic correction.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, of course; that's why a special font is used, with the interword space set to zero. This is not encoding dependent, but *font* dependent. Making a virtual font out of the given is quite easy (but tedious).

Comment: @egreg well, the OP seems to use a font where the interword space is not zero; so he does not get the italic correction you seemed to be asking for.

Comment: @egreg it is possible to set manually `\fontdimen2` but if I recall correctly the assignment is global. So it is a bit complicated if the font is to be used both for text and math, as there is no hook in `TeX` for when exiting from math mode (which we would use to restore this font parameter).

Comment: @jfbu The problem is exactly that assignments to `\fontdimen` are global; it's easier to create a copy of the font and assign `\fontdimen2=0pt` to the copy.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, agreed.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand what I must do. What do you mean to create a copy of the font? How can it works only in math mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's my first time with the tools I will describe below, but let me explain what I just tried (I am sure at least one crucial step is likely to be wrong and will have to be corrected.)

[edited below to make such a presumably necessary addition to the steps]

[of course in the `.tex` source below, this is just for testing, and I brutally reassigned the `letters` symbol font without caring at all for the Greek alphabet; naturally, some additional steps are missing here to separate the Greek letters from the Latin letters, and *only* re-assign the Latin letters to use the Times Italic font in the T1 encoding]

1. I created a temporary directory
2. I then did `tftopl ptmri8r.tfm ptmmi8r.pl`. In this way I obtained a human-readable form of the font metrics for the Times font, from `psnfss`.
3. In my text editor I opened `ptmmi8r.pl` and then replaced `(SPACE R 0.25)` with `(SPACE R 0.0)`.

Near the top of the file `ptmmi8r.pl` created in step 2 there is:

```
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.277)
   (SPACE R 0.25)   <-- this is the 0.25 which I replace with 0.0
   (STRETCH R 0.15)
   (SHRINK R 0.0599985)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.440991)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0599985)
   )
```

continued (sorry I don't know how to resume enumeration with 4, 5, 6...):

4. I saved the file and then did `pltotf ptmmi8r.pl ptmmi8r.tfm`. I now have this file `ptmmi8r.tfm` in my working directory.
5. I created a file `ptmm.map` with the single line: 
   `ptmmi8r NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <8r.enc <utmri8a.pfb`
   This required a bit of research as I had to dig out the `pdftex.map` file from my installation to just copy the line with `ptmri8r` to the one above.
6. I then created the following test file, to be compiled with `pdftex`. And it works.

However: there seems to be a checksum  in the tfm file, and I don't know if modifying the `font dimension 2` parameter needs an update in the checksum.

However two: it seems that the standard `psnfss` use of the Times font is via a virtual font `ptmri8t` and there must be excellent reasons for it. I tried doing the same steps as above but with the `vftovp` and `vptovf` tools, but somehow never managed to understand what to do exactly.

**Update**: ok, so perhaps I now understand some additional steps necessary to get correctly the files for `T1` encoding. Additionally to the above, I have done:

1. `vftovp ptmri8t.vf ptmri8t.tfm ptmmi8t.vpl`
2. I have edited the produced ptmmi8t.vpl in two places: first the fontdimen 2, and then a bit further down the `FONTNAME` entry: I changed it into `(FONTNAME ptmmi8r)`
3. after these two edits, I did `vptovf ptmmi8t.vpl ptmmi8t.vf ptmmi8t.tfm`
4. then `\DeclareFontShape {T1}{ptmm}{m}{it}` uses `ptmmi8t` and not `ptmmi8r`.

**end of update**

Again, my only knowledge in this area dates back to thirty minutes ago, from reading page 9 of [the font installation guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/), then typing `man tftopl` and `man pltotf`. I hope the font experts will come to correct my steps: the only goal was to get a copy of an existing font with its interword space set to zero, so that TeX would automatically insert italic corrections in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% for pdf output only
\pdfmapfile{+ptmm.map}
% ptmmi8r NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <8r.enc <utmri8a.pfb

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{ptmm}{}

% earlier versions had ptmmi8r, but certainly this was wrong

% now that files ptmmi8t.vf and ptmmi8t.tfm have also been prepared
% (see update above)
% additionally to ptmmi8r.tfm, the following presumably should be done:

% (does not matter for the Latin letters in math, but I guess does matter 
% for accented letters or other symbols in text, with `\usefont{t1}{ptmm}{m}{it}`

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptmm}{m}{it}{
   <-> ptmmi8t
}{}

\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{T1}{ptmm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathVersion {standardinterword}
\SetSymbolFont {letters}{standardinterword}{T1}{ptm}{m}{it}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

$f(x)$

% with the edit done for correctly generating also files for T1,
% we can compare the original with the font without interword space: 

{\usefont{T1}{ptmm}{m}{it} àé ù}

{\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{it} àé ù}

$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$

\textit{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\mathversion{standardinterword}

$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$

\mathversion{normal}
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$

\end{document}
```

[image: times with italic corrections in math]

[image: with diacritics and with and without interword space]

Comment: what do you mean with "from psnfss"?

Comment: is there also a `ileki8r.vf` file?

Comment: I mean from the files considered as required part of any LaTeX distribution and dealing with the Times, Helvetica, etc..., fonts.

Comment: Ok. In addition, yes: I've also ileki8r.vf. Following the instructions you suggest, my TeX distribution does not recognize ilem font family.

Comment: Well if there is also a `.vf` file, then maybe you could try `vftovp ileki8r.vf ileki8r.tfm tobeedited.vpl` and then edit the `tobeedited.vpl` file, rename it, and do then `vptovf renamed.vpl renamed.vf renamed.tfm`. However I am at my wits ends here and you are going to need support by someone knowledgeable from then on...

Comment: You may mean `ileki8t.vf` or `ileki8t.vf`. Anyway, the instruction does not work because of a mismatch. In addition, my shell shows that `Character 0 does not exists!`

Comment: yes maybe I meant `ileki8t.vf`. Not being an owner of Legacy Sans I can't test further.

Comment: I've followed all steps above, but I can't see any results: I use dvips and ps2pdf utilities, so I must insert the line `p+ ilem.map` into `config.ps`. Moreover, I obtained `*.vf` files, but they seem not work (in fact the italic glyphs don't produce the correction I mean)

Comment: Hi Lorenzo. It is a long time since I last looked at config.ps. To activate a new map file I would rather add a line to a suitable updmap.cfg and then do updmap (details vary as I am sometimes on TL2010 and at other times on a TL2012; on the latter I own the texmf-local tree and do updmap-sys (not as root)). Have you tested with pdflatex? (using `\pdfmapfile` as above, and all font files in the same repertory as the tex source of the document)

Comment: Not yet: I think that it's the same if I create `t1ilem.fd` file with your instruction above, and then use `\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{T1}{ilem}{m}{it}` in my documents. Anyway, I can actually use `ilemi#` font but it has not its italic correction.

Comment: you can use `\/` to force the use of the italic correction, perhaps you could check this way if the font file actually does provide one?

Comment: `\/` does not work in math mode with legacy font. Maybe I've to create also `ilemi8c.vf` and `ilemi7t.vf`, in order to obtain all encodings of the font. I will retry all instructions, and then post what I will get

Comment: I cannot definitely get the glyph skip I need. I've tried this creating also `ilemi7t.tfm` and `ilemi8c.tfm` files, but it does not work.