# How to use comicsans only for the text but not for the math?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Considerations:

- Most of us might know the Latin alphabet well.
- Some of us might not be familiar with Greek alphabet.

As a result,  comic sans for text contents does not seem to be an issue but it is not the case for math contents with Greek alphabet.

As you can see, the `\lambda` looks unclear, so I want to cancel the comic sans font for the math. Shortly speaking, how to use `comicsans` only for the text but not for the math?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,comicsans}

\begin{document}
If you cannot be the best, be the worst!
\[
\int_a^b f(\lambda)\, \mathrm{d}\lambda = F(b) -F(a)
\]
where bla bla bla \ldots.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [Change math font only in some parts of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14570/5764)

Comment: Oh my! The *lambda* looks ugly! You don't say!?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: OK.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough The lambda is the nicest bit.

Comment: I cannot resist: http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/ I mean, if you're speaking integrals to a five-year-old, everything's fine `:)`

Comment: @Brent.Longborough You must be visually impaired. It's a _lama_ not _lambda_! /sarcasm

Comment: It is the idea of a document which contains both Comic Sans *and* mathematics which is getting me. What could possibly require such a combination?!

Comment: @cfr Perhaps a treatise(!) on Clown Theory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Tested on a MacBook running MacOSX 10.9.2, MacTeX 2013, and LuaTeX 0.76.0. (Update June 2017: The answer given below works with MacOS 10.12.5 "Sierra", MacTeX2017, and LuaTeX 1.0.4 as well.)

A personal remark: To me, the use of Comic Sans in a document is almost invariably not a solution but a problem...

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % choose your favorite Opentype math font here

\begin{document}
If you cannot be the best, be the worst!
\[
\int_a^b f(\lambda)\, \mathrm{d}\lambda = F(b) -F(a)
\]
where bla bla bla \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, when you think nothing could be more ugly than Jabba the Hutt...

Comment: Note that you can use either of `luatex` or `xetex` for this—anything that will work with `fontspec`.

Comment: @SeanAllred - In my experience, the `fontspec` package works equally well with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. However, the same can unfortunately not be said -- at least not currently -- for the `unicode-math` package and Opentype math fonts: There, LuaLaTeX seems to have a decided advantage. More specifically, it's easier for me to generate math material that's not typeset quite right when compiled with XeLaTeX than when compiled with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico It would seem that [it does?](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math) Or is this a planned feature and not an implemented one? Or (more likely now that I think about it) is it the simple matter of an OpenType math font?  **edit:** Ah I see… strange.

Comment: Why worry about it not being 'typeset quite right' when the rest of it is in Comic Sans? (Just wondering.)