# Use custom math font only in parts of a document

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, math-fonts

Very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14570) question I would like to have a different, sans serif math font in (small) parts of my document. As suggested by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101187) answer to said question, this can be acieved using `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and the Computer Modern fonts as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer modern example]

---

However, in my document, I would like to use Roboto as the sans serif font. Doing so results in noticable differences between the document and the math font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[light,medium]{roboto}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\end{document}
```

[image: Roboto example 1]

Note, for example, the different shapes of digit 1 or letter Q. Obviously, I would like to have the math and the document sans serif font as similar as possible. This will certainly not work (easily) for special symbols, but getting numbers, letters and ideally greek letters from the Roboto font would already be great.

---

Changing the first `\SetSymbolFont`, I can already get one step closer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[light,medium]{roboto}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{OT1}{Roboto-LF}{l}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{sans}{OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\sffamily\mathversion{sans}
1234 CQ $1234 CQ$

\end{document}
```

[image: Roboto example 2]

Now the *numbers* are from the correct font! Trying the same approach for the second `\SetSymbolFont` fails, however.

```
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{Roboto-LF}{l}{it}
```

results in

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/Roboto-LF/l/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OML/cmm/m/it' instead on input line 19.
```

and the missing font is evident from the output.

[image: Roboto example 3]

Is there any way I can also get letters (and greek letters) in the right font?

---

In case there are approaches both with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`/`lualatex`, I would be mainly interested in `pdflatex`, since I am also using the `microtype` package, which is well-known to be not fully compatible with `xelatex`/`lualatex`. If the latter can do the thing, but `pdflatex` cannot, I may still look into ditching `microtype`, though.

Comment: Can't be done. (At least, cannot be done in any way you could possibly want to do it.) OML is a maths encoding. Roboto is not provided in that encoding (presumably it will lack many of the characters required).

Comment: That's what I suspected might be the answer. Is this also true for `xelatex`? From what I understand, `unicode-math` can be used with any font, but I may be mistaken in that. Could `\DeclareMathVersion` be translated to that scenario?

Comment: `unicode-math` needs a maths font(s) i.e. something with a MATH font table. I don't know if you could use it to take letters from a non-maths font. `mathspec` (I think the name is) might be an option. However, I don't know that that would make it any easier. You could presumably redeclare a bunch of maths stuff, but you could do that anyway.