# Switching between math fonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am working on a book that feeds on the ''Fourier'' package (I am using pdflatex not xelatex or lualatex). However, there are sections under the title ''applications'' that are desired to be of a different font.

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{application}
 Here go say ''[english]{babel}'' package and ''{mathpazo,mathabx}'' package. 
\end{application}
...
\end{document}
```

What I found was ''unicode-math'' which is specific to xelatex to the best of my knowledge. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `unicode-math` package -- note: it's not spelled "uni-code math" -- is *not* specific to XeLaTeX. It works just as well under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Please tell us why you think you must use pdfLaTeX. Put differently, why do you seem to be averse to using XeLaTeX or LuaLateX?

Comment: thanks for your information. I'm using a publisher's template which is not xelatex. I can do nothing about it.

Comment: If you need to follow a publishers template anyway you probably can't change the font setup. Otherwise if you want to change the font you probably can switch relatively easily to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I think you found the answer in [Change math font only in some parts of a document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/change-math-font-only-in-some-parts-of-a-document). (do link to the answers you found.) Fundamentally it's possible without unicode-math, although you need lots of LaTeX programming knowledge to get the effect...

Comment: alternatively, make a MWE and specify your specific need so people can give you some code (with the risk that you will not be able to understand the code, and it may break in other unexpected use cases)